isystem forces header to C linkage
This smells similar to - but is different from - Why does OpenBSD's G++ make system headers default to C linkage? This is not BSD, but instead the Arm g++ cross-compiler.
With this trivial pair of source files -
mbed/can.h
template <typename T> void ftest2(T t) { }

src/outer.cpp
template <typename T> void ftest0(T t) { }
#include <can.h>
template <typename T> void ftest1(T t) { }

The following command fails:
/arm-none-eabi-gcc/7.3.1-1.2.2/.content/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ \
    -isystem"mbed" \
    -c "src/outer.cpp"

In file included from src/outer.cpp:2:0:
mbed/can.h:1:1: error: template with C linkage
 template <typename T> void ftest2(T t) { }

This is deeply strange, since neither of the template definitions in the CPP file fail, and (seemingly) nothing changes from the CPP to the H. I can only assume that gcc is doing some forbidden magic with -isystem and forcing the header to be interpreted as a C file, but I have no idea why, and I need that to stop. I need -isystem since, in real life, the mbed code is littered with warnings that I need to suppress for that directory tree.
This mysterious comment seems to be exactly my problem:

Just as a hint for future readers: If you pass an include directory to gcc via -isystem instead of -I, some versions may implicitly apply C linkage. – Jan Schatz Jul 1, 2019 at 15:02

But there is no hint as to how it may be resolved.

how it may be resolved. sooo extern "C++" { ... }? I need -isystem since, in real life, the mbed code Bottom line, why not use mbed to compile mbed? And also, mbed has been discontinued

@KamilCuk OK; where? Surrounding the #include ? mbed has third-party code and it seems like poor practice to modify every one of its headers to have an extern declaration.

where? I believe you would have to make a copy of all headers and add extern "C++" { everywhere. But anyway, why use -isystem instead of -I? can.h is not a standard header. Is this XY question? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

@KamilCuk As I said, -I is not good enough and I need -isystem to suppress the many warnings in the library.

It turns out what I actually need is CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH; from the manpage:

CPATH
C_INCLUDE_PATH
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
Each variable's value is a list of directories separated by a
special character, much like PATH, in which to look for
header files.  The special character, "PATH_SEPARATOR", is
target-dependent and determined at GCC build time.  For
Microsoft Windows-based targets it is a semicolon, and for
almost all other targets it is a colon.
CPATH specifies a list of directories to be searched as if
specified with -I, but after any paths given with -I options
on the command line.  This environment variable is used
regardless of which language is being preprocessed.
The remaining environment variables apply only when
preprocessing the particular language indicated.  Each
specifies a list of directories to be searched as if
specified with -isystem, but after any paths given with
-isystem options on the command line.

